# How to Mock the following case using PowerMock or Easy Mock or Mockito or all

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, easymock, powermock

I have the following class

```
    public class TestClass{
    ParamObject paramObject = null;

    public TestClass(ParamObject paramObject){
        this.paramObject = paramObject;
    }

    public String getQuery(String field){

        String sql = field + "sometext" + getName();
    }

    private String getName(){
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
        return obj.getName();
    }

}
```

I want to mock the above getName method of the class. The constructor argument is available in the Test class. How do I do this.

```
@Test(groups = { "UNIT", "CS_RAJAN" })
public void TestClass_Unit_Test() throws Exception {
    ParamObject paramObject = get();//some param object

    //some way to pass the paramObject to the class and mock the getName() method so that it returns "ABC"

}
```

Comment: If that is your entire class, then the question should be why do you want to test it? It's a private method that is never called. Not withstanding that, I would say that you should not be testing private methods - they define how your class is implemented, not how it behaves. You should target you testing around behaviours as implementations may change over time ( and your tests will start to fail for no valid reason )

Comment: It seems to me that what you actually want to do is stub the creation of the `SomeObject`, so that you can test this using a dummy `SomeObject` whose "name" is known.  If you can confirm that this would meet your need, I will post a detailed answer describing how to do this.

Comment: Actually I want to test the public method getQuery(String field). I want to mock the private method to return a text (say "ABC") so that when I call getQuery("Hello"), I want to receive "HellosometextABC" on the test method. The SomeObject is a Context object which is properly initialized when browsing from applicaiton. This is the replica scenario I want to test, and I am sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is something like this in the testClass

```
ParamObject paramObject = get();//Some instance
TestClass t = PowerMock.createPartialMock(
        TestClass.class, "getName", null, paramObject);

String expected = "ABC";

PowerMock.expectPrivate(t, "getName").andReturn(
        expected);
PowerMock.replay(t);
```